Is it appropiate to add a interaction term between time and the variable of interest in a two way fixed effects?
I'm interested in estimating the effect of countries' economic development on their level of democracy. To do that I'm using two-way fixed effects. The fixed effects are unit and time fixed effects.
I have read that an implicit assumption when working with fixed effects models is that the effect size is constant over time; therefore, I should add an interaction term between the coefficient that I'm interested in estimating and a variable for time. In this case the variable could be year. This interaction term could then indicate whether the effect of the coefficient is constant over time.
Is this actually appropriate given the model already includes time fixed effects?

Please add a citation to your reading where that statement is made.

Welcome to Cross Validated!  Could you please show more detail about the way you have built time into your model.
